# Ruby - explain code snippet hash sorter

Tags: ruby, hash

I use this code for sorting Hash; 
I've got no idea how its works.
please explain to me:

```
def foo(hash)
  Hash[hash.sort]
end

irb(main):001:0> h = {1=>'z', 3=>'x', 2=>'y'}
=> {1=>"z", 3=>"x", 2=>"y"}
irb(main):002:0> Hash[h.sort]
=> {1=>"z", 2=>"y", 3=>"x"}
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: This can also be written as `Hash[hash.sort_by(&:first)]`, where `hash.sort_by(&:first)` sorts the key-value pairs by key. If the hash is large this may be faster than using `sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enumerable#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) reutrns an sorted array of key-value pairs:

```
h = {b: 1, a: 2}
h.sort
# => [[:a, 2], [:b, 1]]
```

[`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) create a new hash base on the argument:

```
Hash[h.sort]
# => {:a=>2, :b=>1}
```

BTW, if you use Ruby 2.1+, you can use [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_h) instead:

```
h.sort.to_h
# => {:a=>2, :b=>1}
```

Comment: For completeness: in ruby v2 you can just do `h.sort.to_h`

Comment: i swear firts things i did was to look in the doc;

Comment: @BroiSatse, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer to include `Array#to_h`. BTW, it's introduced in Ruby 2.1.